# Hot and Active should not take into account Feeds

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, sorting, activity

In the chat, a room is sorted at the top in the active or hot tab if the activity is from the "feeds user".

I think said activity should be ignored for this kind of things.

Comment: Oh look at me! I'm so special because I got invited to a private pre-beta chat site.

Comment: @jon, what are you talking about? There was an open 3 days beta..

Comment: there's a new *super special* pre-beta. Don't act like you don't know Mr. I-Think-I'm-So-Special.